# How to create a unique name out of random data and set it to random data relevantly

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using c# winforms with entity framework.

I'm developing a program to read from excel files and store the data appropriately into my database.

each excel file has the following information has Tournament Details

there are two kinds of poker tournaments

1- Daily Tournaments (starts and ends within that day)

2- Weekly tournaments (starts on a day and ends in 3-5 days)

with the daily tournaments everything is fine since they start and end at the same day. The exact same tournament name may exist in a different excel file
with a different date of course so  "Tournament Name" + "Tournament Date" is my Identifier for the daily Tournaments.

I'm trying to set an Identifier name for the weekly tournaments but having trouble and can't seem to come with a proper solution, so even though most people wont like this I've decided to ask for an advice here.

below is a sample image for the weekly tournament:

on the below tournament only two things will change each day on the excel file

1-Date

2-Name of the Tournament

for the other days the tournament name will be like this in the excel:
Main Event D1B
Main Event D1C(some times only D1A and D1B and no D1C) 
Main Event D2 
Main Event Final

so what I want to do is:

I want to give the same identifier name to D1A,D1B,D1C, D2, and Final

all excels are random inside the folder and also 
please not that event no and names are not unique so at some time in history or future Main Event D1A with event no 10 may occur.

[image]

Comment: Can you use a Guid? In C# you can 
var id =  Guid.NewGuid();

Comment: @Tony never heard nor had experience with guid, will look into it to see if it will help, thanks

Comment: Hash the unique name, that would give you a longer random looking string. You can't go back from a hash, but rehashing the name again will generate the same hash as before.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tony pointed out, you could use Guid to do it. Another alternative is to use SHA256 to generate your ID. This solution is slower though.

```
SHA256 shaAlg = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
byte[] shaDigest = shaAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(randomDataString));
return BitConverter.ToString(shaDigest);
```